# Why isn't responsivevoice.org working with my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, voice-recognition, voice

I'm trying to add a Hindi Male accent to my website which currently has a US Male accent. I used a website called responsivevoice.org which gave me a unique link that I needed to put before the closing of the body tag so I did as told. It wasn't working so I put another script src that I saw someone put on their website when they were using responsivevoice.org, this generated 4 things in the console. One of them said that the voice support is ready and the other one said responsive voice r1 (so I believe I'm getting somewhere.) However, one was a verbose and the last one was an error that came when I put the first script src. How do I fix this? Btw I'm using my HTML and JS in one file. Can someone please answer?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.talk');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const greetings = [
    'If you are good im good too.', 
    'Im doin alright', 
    'doing well.'
];
const weather = [
    'Ask the weatherman!', 
    'I recommend checking your phone or the news ' 
    
];
const name = [
 'My name is techwaala', 
 'its techwaala, because I love to code!'
];
const hello = [
 'Why hello! How are you doing today?', 
 'Hey there How are you?'
];
const hru = [
 'thats great!', 
 'Im so sorry to hear that', 
 'Feel better soon!'
];
const SpeechRecognition = 
 window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.onstart = function() {
 console.log('voice is activated speak into the mic');
};
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
 const current = event.resultIndex;
 
 const transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
 content.textContent = transcript;
 readOutLoud(transcript);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 recognition.start();
});

function readOutLoud(message) {
 
 const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
 speech.text = 'I dont know what you said';
 if(message.includes('how are you')) {
   const finalText = 
   greetings[Math.floor(Math.random() * greetings.length)];
   speech.text = finalText;
  
 } 
 if(['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'hi there', 'hey there', 'hi techwala', 'hey techwala','hello techwala']
 .some(word => message.includes(word))) {
    const finalText = hello[Math.floor(Math.random() * hello.length)];
    speech.text = finalText;
 
}
 if(['whats your name', 'your name']
 .some(word => message.includes(word))) {
    const finalText = name[Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)];
    speech.text = finalText;
}
if(['how\'s the weather', 'what\'s the weather like', 'is it sunny', 'is it raining', 'is it cloudy', 'is it snowing']
 .some(word => message.includes(word))) {
    const finalText = weather[Math.floor(Math.random() * weather.length)];
    speech.text = finalText;
}
 
 speech.volume = 1;
 speech.rate = 1;
 speech.pitch = 1;
 window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 
</head>
<body>
<button class="talk">Talk</button>
<h3 class="content"></h3>
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script src="//code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js?key=NNni6L33"></script>
</body>
</html>
```